# jquery - slideToggle not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a problem with the `slideToggle` function in `jQuery`. It is not smooth at all. Whenever I click the "See More" button, the content that should `slideToggle`, just pops out with no effect what-so-ever.

This is the HTML code:

```
<td class="third">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary upgrade1">See More</a>
</td>                           

<tr class="see_more" id="see_more">
      <td colspan="3" class="see_more_content">Hello! How are you doing</td>
</tr>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.third{
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.see_more{
    display:none;

}
.see_more_content{
    text-align:center;
}
```

And finally, the javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){ 
                 $(".upgrade1").click(function() {
                     $("#see_more").slideToggle("slow");
                  });  
               });
     </script>
```

I have read article "Animation Jump - quick tip", but I don't think that is the problem here. Since I haven't specified any `margin` or `padding` to the content that should `slideToggle`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try slidetoggling a div rather than a table row. To accomplish this, make both the row and div hidden, show the row, then slideDown the div, and reverse for hiding of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Table Rows don't seem to slide. You should try to find a workaround by using DIV instead. They slide and animate much better. You could also wrap the content into a div, and slide that? Maybe that would push the table row to imitate a slide.

Comment: Yep, I won't bother posting my example now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are running a `slideToggle` on a table row.  Table rows do not play nice with some css.  This means in some cases, it will not slide, but just show up when it is finally visible.