# Collapsing table rows with multiple tbody elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    ....
    .... 10s of records like this
</table>
```

I want to make each tbody element clickable (collapsible) so that in a collapsed state, I would get a summary of what is inside (say, `Customer 1 | 3 Entries`) and in an expanded state, I would get to see the actual rows.

Can this be done for the table structured as shown above?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ju4xH/

Comment: Customer 1 | 3 Entries I didnt get this ? will you please make it more clear .. I understand you need each tbody colapsable and when click on that header expand that tbody .

Comment: @rahularyansharma: That's just an example that in the collapsed state, the collapsed row shows the total number of internal rows. For instance, in my table, for Customer 1 there are three internal rows.

Comment: It is more user friendly to have the summary row static and always displayed with a button to collapse or expand the detail rows. Clicking anywhere to collapse the tbody is an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: may be you don't find my answer slideToggle("slow") smooth just because Table Rows don't seem to slide.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931057/jquery-slidetoggle-not-smooth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little messy and the animations don't work (I'm guessing it's because it's on the `<tr>`s, but here's what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").on("click", "tbody", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var myTRs = $this.children("tr");

        if ($this.hasClass("collapsed")) {
            $this.removeClass("collapsed");
            myTRs.first().remove();            
            myTRs.show();
        } else {
            $this.addClass("collapsed");
            var newInfo = myTRs.first().children("td").first().text() + " | " + myTRs.length + " entries";
            myTRs.hide();
            $this.prepend($("<tr><td colspan='3'>" + newInfo + "</td></tr>").hide()).find("tr").first().slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZhqAf/1/

When you click a non-collapsed `<tbody>`, it will hide the rows and prepend a new one with the details you wanted. When you click a collapsed `<tbody>`, it removes the new "details" row, and shows the original rows.

Comment: +1 Thank you. For some reason, there is some unwanted delay when collapsing an expanded row. Do you happen to know why this is the case? I've tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Legend Yeah, it's because of the sliding animations. Like I said in the answer, the animations don't work (probably because they're happening to a `<tr>`. Anyways, I updated my answer's code and fiddle without using them (probably should've just done that in the first place). So let me know if that fixes what you meant, and if you need more help with this :)

Answer (score 2):

I have included header for each row by counting the number of rows in that `tbody` and after insert bind the click event on each header to show content of that `tbody` .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody').each(function(){
        var num=$(this).children().length;
       // alert(num);
       $(this).before("<div id='header' class='header'>"+num +" entries </div>");
        //alert($(this).html());
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.header').on('click',function(){
       $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/Ju4xH/16/)

**EDITED**

if you really want slide animation you can wrap all `tbody` also in a div . so `slideToggel`  will give you animation also. You can use this as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody').each(function(){
        var num=$(this).children().length;
       // alert(num);
       $(this).before("<div id='header' class='header'>"+num +" entries </div>");
        //alert($(this).html());
        $(this).wrap('<div class="new" />');
        $('.new').hide();
    });
    $('.header').on('click',function(){

       $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        $(this)
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK FOR EDITED PART](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/Ju4xH/19/)

Comment: Even I am curious why this was down voted. I just saw this approach and it looks concise and clean. Anyone, care to comment? I up voted to compensate. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure what browser this was tested on back in 2013, but this isn't valid markup, and under my current browsers this example fails. `div` isn't a valid child of table. By introducing a div here, the browser prematurely closes the table (or at least most do... the behavior is unexpected so browsers take their best guess) and what you get is an orphaned `tr`.